# Methods to check form validity and to count invalid form fields

Tags: java, validation, comparative-review, form

I have two these methods. Their loops are pretty similar. I'd like to refactor it to avoid duplicate nested loops. How could I do that?

```
@Override
public boolean isValid() {
    for (final FormSection formSection : getFormSections()) {
        for (final Component fieldComponent : formSection) {
            boolean isFieldValid = ((Field)fieldComponent).isValid();
            if(!isFieldValid){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private int countErrors() {
    int errorAmount = 0;
    for (final FormSection formSection : getFormSections()) {
        for (final Component fieldComponent : formSection) {
            boolean isFieldValid = ((Field)fieldComponent).isValid();
            if(!isFieldValid){
                errorAmount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return errorAmount;
}
```

I've tried to use interface but it doesn't look good.

```
interface FieldHandler {
    boolean process(AtomicInteger number);
}

@Override
public boolean isValid() {
    return handleTextFieldsInTabs(new FieldHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean process(AtomicInteger number) {
            return false;
        }
    }, null);
}

boolean handleTextFieldsInTabs(FieldHandler fieldHandler, AtomicInteger number) {
    for (final FormSection formSection : getFormSections()) {
        for (final Component fieldComponent : formSection) {
            boolean isFieldValid = ((Field)fieldComponent).isValid();
            if(!isFieldValid && !fieldHandler.process(number)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private int countErrors() {
    final AtomicInteger errorAmount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    handleTextFieldsInTabs(new FieldHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean process(AtomicInteger number) {
            number.incrementAndGet();
            return true;
        }
    }, errorAmount);
    return errorAmount.intValue();
}
```

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: Users can use Java 7 to run the code. That's why I need a non-lambda way.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party library like Apache's `common-collections4` or Google's `guava`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google's `guava`, I would suggest:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid() {
  // Firstly, flat your Iterable<Iterable<Component>> getFormSections()
  // into Iterable<Component>.
  // Then we use a Predicate to check whether there is any match.
  return Iterables.all(
    Iterables.concat(getFormSections()), validComponents()); 
}

@Override
public int countErrors() {
   return Iterables.size(
      Iterables.filter(Iterables.concat(getFormSections()), Predicates.not(validComponents()));

}

// - Positive names is always preferable
// - This method is static simply because it does not access to any instance varibles. It is easier to extract it out into another class.
private static Predicate<Component> validComponent() {
  new Predicate<Component>() {
      @Override
      public boolean apply(Component input) {
        return // your logic here
      }
    };
}
```